# Convexity radius function on manifold is continuous

Tags: riemannian-geometry, geodesic

> Let $(M, g)$ be a Riemannian manifold. For $p \in M$, the convexity radius at $p$, denoted by $\mathrm{conv}(p)$, is defined as $$\mathrm{conv}(p) := \sup \{r > 0 \ \mid \ B_g(p, r) \text{ is a geodesically convex geodesic ball} \} \in (0, \infty]. $$ It is known that $\mathrm{conv}(p) > 0$ for all $p \in M$.

I would like to show that the map $$\mathrm{conv} : M \to (0, \infty], \quad p \mapsto \mathrm{conv}(p) $$ is continuous.

I tried showing that, around a point $p \in M$ where $\mathrm{conv}(p) < \infty$ is finite, the $\mathrm{conv}$ map is $1$-Lipschitz. For $q \in M$, due to symmetry, is suffices to show that
$$\mathrm{conv}(q) \geq \mathrm{conv}(p) - d_g(p,q). $$
If $d_g(p, q) \geq \mathrm{conv}(p)$, we cleary have $$\mathrm{conv}(q) \geq 0 \geq \mathrm{conv}(p) - d_g(p,q). $$
If, however, $d_g(p, q) < \mathrm{conv}(p)$, I am not sure how to prove that $$\mathrm{conv}(q) \geq \mathrm{conv}(p) - d_g(p,q), $$ because I am not sure that the geodesic ball of radius $\mathrm{conv}(p) - d_g(p,q)$ around $q$ is geodesically convex.

Also, I do not how to prove continuity in the case that $\mathrm{conv}(p) = \infty$.

Comment: The proof of continuity has two parts: Lower semicontinuity and upper semicontinuity. Can you prove either one of these?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I do not think so.

Comment: A supplement on reference: this is problem 6-6 in *Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds* by John M.Lee. Maybe we should @Jack Lee :)

Comment: I think this is a related discussion: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/745813/is-there-any-relationship-between-the-convexity-radii-of-two-near-points-in-a

Comment: @Yunmath I looked into the proof of this result in Klingenberg's book, but it is not useful...It states the it is "trivial from the definition" that the $\mathrm{conv}$ map is $1$-Lipschitz. Moreover, the book does not treat the case $\mathrm{conv}(p) = \infty$ from my understanding.

Comment: @user1003515 I think the definition of convexity radius in Klingenberg's book is different from yours, he use a notion called strongly geodesically convex. By the way, I think in the link above, it has an example showing that the convexity radius is not continuous if we use your definition.

Comment: Some thoughts here. By applying a limit process, we can show the value at each point is no less than the limsup of values around the point since we are dealing with open geodesic ball. But I cannot address the other side.

Comment: @juggler could you please explain more detail? I think the issue is that, in the definition above, we do not know if we have a geodesically convex ball B, whether other metric balls contained in B (may not have the same center) is also convex. I think this is the reason why Klingerberg introduce the notion of strongly geodesically convex in his book.

Comment: @Yunmath To clarify, I follow Lee’s definition that being geodesically convex means any two points in it have a unique minimizing geodesic segment that lies in the ball.

Comment: If $x_i$ converge to $x$ with convex geodesic balls $B_{r_i}(x_i)=:B_i$ and $r_i$ converge to $r$, then any two points in $B_r(x)$ lie in $B_i$ both for sufficiently large $i$, so their minimizing geodesic segment lies in the ball at $x$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just think about a small issue in your argument, how can we show that the minimizing geodesic does not touch the boundary of $B_r(x)$?

Comment: @Yunmath You’re right. I don’t know how to adjust it. Maybe the issue is not as small.

Answer (score 1):

The key part of the proof is the fact that if $\gamma$ is a minimizing geodesic segment joining two points of a geodesically convex geodesic ball $B_r(p)$, then $d_g(p,\gamma(t))$ attains a maximum at one of its endpoints.
This is from Problem 6-5 in *Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds* by John M.Lee or Lemma 4.1 from *Riemannian Geometry* by Do Carmo.

To prove $$\text{conv}(p)\geq \text{conv}(q)-d_g(p,q)$$ when the RHS is positive, let $\text{conv}(q) = R$. For any $r<R$, the ball $B_r(q)$ is geodesically convex and $B_{r-d_g(q,p)}(p) \subseteq B_r(q)$.
For any two points $x_1,x_2\in B_{r-d_g(q,p)}(p) \subseteq B_r(q)$ there is a minimizing curve $\gamma$ segment in $B_r(q)$ joining these two points. Now
$$ d_g(p,\gamma(t)) \leq d_g(q,p) + d_g(q,\gamma(t)) $$
Since $d_g(q,\gamma(t))$ attains its maximum at $x_1$ or $x_2$,
so does $d_g(p,\gamma(t))$ i.e., the curve $\gamma(t)\in B_{r-d_g(q,p)}(p)$. Therefore
$$ conv(p) \geq r-d_g(p,q) $$
Since this is true for all $r<R$, the desired result follows.

Note that this proof also works for the case $conv(q)=\infty$.